# multi-group CFA with ordinal variables not working because of low frequency

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I'm trying to run a multi-group CFA of psychometric tool using likert scale data. I have converted the data to ordinal and am using WLSMV estimation with theta paramterization on a colleagues recommendation. The code is shown below for the model and the initial cfa.

```
model_ord <- ' depression =~ f1h09_ordinal+f1h16_ordinal+f1h17_ordinal+f1h18_ordinal+f1h35_ordinal+f1h50_ordinal
          anxiety =~ f1h01_ordinal+f1h12_ordinal+f1h19_ordinal+f1h38_ordinal+f1h45_ordinal+f1h49_ordinal
          somatization =~ f1h02_ordinal+f1h07_ordinal+f1h23_ordinal+f1h29_ordinal+f1h33_ordinal+f1h37_ordinal
          depression~~anxiety
          anxiety~~somatization
          depression~~somatization'

"'# use the cfa function from the lavaan package to fit a CFA of our model
fit_ord <- cfa(model_ord, data=d_ord, estimator='WLSMV', std.lv=TRUE, parameterization="theta")"'
```

Although I do get the following warning, the initial cfa runs fine.

```
Warning message:
In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
    does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
    (= -1.030933e-16) is smaller than zero. This may be a symptom that
    the model is not identified.
```

However, when I break it up by groups I run into a different issue (code and error message below).

```
config_ord <- cfa(model_ord, data=d_ord, estimator='WLSMV', std.lv=TRUE, group="f103", parameterization="theta")
Error in lav_samplestats_step1(Y = Data, wt = wt, ov.names = ov.names,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: some categories of variable `f1h35_ordinal' are empty in group 1; frequencies are [75 15 2 0 0]
```

The issue is that no male in the sample (group 1) had responded "quite a bit" or "extremely" on item 35, and the low frequencies are wrecking the cfa. What is interesting is that I get the same error message when I use a different grouping (below), but the cfa still runs.

```
config_ord2 <- cfa(model_ord2, data=d_ord, estimator='WLSMV', std.lv=TRUE, group="binaryrelationship", parameterization="theta")
Error in lav_samplestats_step1(Y = Data, wt = wt, ov.names = ov.names,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: some categories of variable `f1h35_ordinal' are empty in group 1; frequencies are [98 22 4 3 0]
```

Does anyone know why this would be a problem for one grouping and not another? How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you get an error after both calls to the `cfa()` function, neither call should run and or return a fit. Your code examples seem to indicate this is the case too.

As far as fixing this, there are a few options in your case:

1. You could remove item 35 from your model.
2. You could collapse the levels of item 35 for all groups. Because no males responded "quite a bit" or "extremely", you would have to collapse the scores of anyone who did respond "quite a bit" or "extremely" down to whatever the third level of item is.
3. You could collect more data, and hope you get males who responded "quite a bit" or "extremely" on item 35.

You could also consider using a different statistical technique, such as multilevel modelling, if it isn’t necessary to your research question to run a multigroup CFA.